# javascript: replace all dots with commas except those that are decimal seperators

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all dots with commas, instead of those dots that are used in numbers as decimal seperators.
Examples:

- `test.test` `->` `test,test`
- `1.2 test` `->` `1.2 test`
- `1.2.test` `->` `1.2,test`
- `test.test aaa (bbb. dddd 1.2g)` `->` `test,test aaa (bbb, dddd 1.2g)`

First, I thought that I can do like this:

- match only thouse points that are just after any letters ([a-z]*?[.]), but in this case the third examples is not working correctly

Can you give me some clues?

Comment: [You may use `\.(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/5lIYb3/1)

Comment: How do you want to treat a dot in "test.5"?

Comment: Leave as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead in your regex:

```
str = str.replace(/\.(?!\d)/g, ',');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5lIYb3/1/)

`\.(?!\d)` matches dot if it is not followed by a digit.

Comment: It will also retain `1.2fs` but OP only wants to retain *dots that are used in numbers as decimal seperators*

Comment: Maybe I was not precise enough. 1.2fs should leave as it is.

Comment: Yes, this regex would leave `1.2fs` as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Without lookibehind assertions (introduced in ES2018) it may be a bit tricky

```
str = str.replace(/^\.|(\D)\.|(\d)\.(?!\d)/g, "$1$2,");
```

This one passes all your tests.

Or, with ES2018 lookbehind assertions you can use

```
str = str.replace(/(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)/g, ",");
```